# Performance comparison between libc++ and libstdc++ on Linux

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, libstdc++, libc++

Is there any comprehensive performance comparison between the two standard library on Linux?

I have searched for quite some time but found nothing.

The compiler will be `clang`, as `libc++` on Linux only works with `clang`.

`libc++` is not feature complete on Linux (`exception_ptr` is not implemented yet, but it is not a concern to me). On the other hand, it has more C++11/14 features than `libstdc++` has. Newer versions of `libstdc++` does provide more support (e.g., `regex` in GCC 4.9), but it is somehow difficult to ask `clang` to use newer version other than the distro's default. It can be done, but I haven't found any non-ugly solution.

It is easy to have newer GCC installed in a custom location and build executables to link to the newer `libstdc++`, but I don't see how one can has the exec to choose the new library *at runtime* without inject the new library into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which changes the behavior of everything in the system that use C++. `RPATH` is a possible solution, but still I think it is quite ugly and, maybe I am mistaken, it also changes the behavior of other libraries that the same executable links to.

Above is the main reason I am wanting to switch to `libc++` (better C++11/14 support without messing with system executables, the old `libstdc++` is only linked for ABI support). However, I am concerned with the performance. Just a few thing that I like to see in a performance comparison (another reason is that I found reporting bugs of `libc++` is much easier. Reading `libc++`'s source when a bug occurs is quite pleasant, the coding is very neat, while reading `libstdc++`'s source, I found I got lost more than often):

- STL container, mainly `vector`, performance (`resize`, `push_back`, etc., sometime they just cannot be avoided)
- Numerical libraries, mainly `<random>` (`<cmath>` is irrelevant, which I believe the two library has no difference since it simply depends on system `libm`, which is extremely slow and outdated on Linux, and I don't use the `glibc`'s math library anyway)
- `<algorithm>`, `std::copy`, `std::fill` etc. Again, some time you just cannot avoid them (mainly when the interface you want to provide is generic and you don't want to specialize every function for pointers to explicitly call `memset` etc.). So it will be better to know if the libraries performance on these functions (e.g., is the implementation low overhead enough such that it allows the compiler to see what's going on and can thus perform certain optimizations only possible for pointers. I think this also depends on the STL's implementation of iterators).

Comment: No spotlight on `std::string`?